# Showing the a column as text in Power Pivot Table next to a summarized variable (Power Pivot)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot

I have an Excel table like this:

```
AZIENDA  |  CF  |  Fatturato  | Semester
A        |  333d|  10         | 1 
A        |  333d|  20         | 2 
B        |  145 |  34         | 1
B        |  145 |  10         | 2  
C        |  111 |  5          | 1
```

Using Power Pivot, I want this outcome as a Pivot Table:

```
AZIENDA  | Fatturato   | CF
A        | 30          | 333d 
B        | 44          | 145
C        | 5           | 111
```

Main problem is the creation of the column CF. I tried to create this measure

```
=CONCATENATEX(Tabella1,Tabella1[CF],",")
```

But it does not work.
Any better idea?

Comment: If `CF` is always duplictes, just change that field to show the `MAX()` or `MIN()`?

Comment: "We can't summarize this field with Max because it's not a supported calculation for text data types". There are some letters somewhere. Better update the question, sorry

Comment: Well, if you load your data into powerquery you can simply group by colums AZIENDA and CF. Some shuffeling of columns will get you exactly what you are after. I don't think you can get text values into Pivot Table.

Comment: Indeed, it is possible. For instance look here https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/july-2018-excel-reporting-text-in-a-pivot-table/ . Problem is I don't have a variable to add in columns. All the examples I found are like this. Usually a variable with dummy values used in 'Column' of Pivot Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK with the `CF` column coming before `Fatturato`, then you can just stick it on the rows and use Show in Tabular Form under Report Layout dropdown on the Design tab.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Not a great general solution but might be a good option for some situations.

Comment: thank you!! I missed that option in that dropdown tab

Answer (score 0):

If the values in column CF are always the same then you can use LASTNONBLANK in a measure and drag that to your values field

```
CF:=CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(Tabella1[CF],0))
```